# How do analog photography light meters work?

Tags: canon, aperture, light, metering

I have a Canon AE-1 film camera. It works well and I've several FD, FL and Vivitar lenses.

For recent digital cameras, I know how the light meter works. However, with this old camera, I would shed light on one specific point.

For full-aperture metering, the meter does the measurement with light rays that come through the lens. There are 4 factors:

- ISO/ASA (known by the camera)
- speed (also known)
- quantity of light (what is actually measured)
- aperture (**not** known by the film camera ...)

You see where I'm going here. In full-aperture metering, aperture is a factor that depends on the lens and can vary ! I've some 1.4, 1.8, 2.8 and 3.5 lenses. How the light meter can do a correct computation without knowing the aperture of the lens ?

For example, on a sunny day with 100 ASA film, 1/1000 speed and my f/1.4 lens, the light meter of my AE-1 will indicate f/5.6. But if I take another lens, e.g. a f/2.8 one, the quantity of light receive by the light meter will be less than with the previous one... Thus, it will indicate may be f/4 or f/2.8, or some other value. And one of the readings must be wrong, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the lens mount. The Canon FD mount has two *mechanical* communication paths from the lens to the camera:

- An **Aperture Signal Lever** that tells the camera whether the lens is at full aperture or, if not, how much it is stepped down.
- A **Full Aperture Signal Pin** that tells the camera what its full aperture actually is - so the camera *does* know! When connected, it depresses a matching pin in the camera body. In variable-aperture zoom lenses, working the zoom moves this pin.

The details are explained on [this page](http://www.baytan.org/prak/fulapmet.html).

Note that FL mount lenses to not have the Full Aperture Signal Pin, so with such a lens, your meter actually shouldn't be able to tell you what aperture to set, only how much to stop down (or up).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, my question was about my FL lenses (which work with full-aperture metering). With these lenses, as you said, the camera doesn't know the aperture. Is there no technique / tips to deduce which aperture set with the meter info ? If I take a 3.5 FL 17mm lens, if the AE-1 meter level show "5.6", I know that I must stop down, but how could I know the best aperture ?

Comment: @AntiClimacus: Actually, according to the Canon website (http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=13715 ) you *definitely* cannot use full-aperture metering with an FL lens - instead you use stopped-down metering, which basically means you have to vary aperture until the meter shows 5.6 - that means that your current aperture is correct, not that you have to change it.

Comment: Ok ! Last question: I'm just curious to know the *default* value of the **full aperture signal pin**, when I use a FL lens. Indeed, with the knowledge of this default value, I could use it to compute myself the best aperture (with the aperture info of meter). E.g., if this value is f/1.8, I can directly use the meter light information with my 1.8 FL lens :D

Comment: @AntiClimacus: sorry, can't help you with that, not sure if there is such a default behaviour.

Comment: Your link is dead (March 2018)